# Alternative way of sending webgl context as binary data WITHOUT using gl.readPixels

Tags: javascript, websocket, three.js, webgl

I created two html clients that communicate with each other using a websocket server. One client draw a 3D model on it's canvas using Three.js and sends the canvas context, which is webGl, as binary data to the other client thought the websocket server.

The problem is that the readPixels() method is too slow. I need to make this stream as fluid as possible.

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

    var ctx = renderer.getContext();        

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(1280 * 720 * 4);

    ctx.readPixels(0,0,1280, 720, ctx.RGBA, ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteArray);

    socket.send(byteArray.buffer);

}
```

renderer is a THREE.WebGLRenderer.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Here is the code that I used as basis for the 3D drawing [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_effects_peppersghost.html)

Comment: readPixels is too slow compared to what?? Data transfer must be much more slower, isnt it?

Comment: Is too slow compared to using context.getImageData().data,  but unfortunately it only work with 2D context.

Comment: Some useful information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices#General_performance_tips

Comment: It says that readPixels is very slow and should be avoided. The browser also alert this, saying that readPixels is deprecated and can be very slow. The problem is that everywhere I search do not give an alternative way =/

Comment: The only thing that I found was Pixel Buffer Object, but it doesn't work in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");` (or `png`) to grab the imagedata, that's a reliable way of getting the image data from a WebGL context. I'm not so sure how performance compares to readPixels, I've only ever used it for screenshots.

Comment: Really interesting this method, and its kind fast.  I will try to send the dataURL through the socket as a string file and draw on the other client canvas.

Comment: It worked super fast! Thanks!  The only thing is that the canvas that is receiving the dataURL is flickering. I'm putting the `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");` method underneath the `renderer.render( scene, camera );`, any idea how to stop this flickering?